# Is it possible to implement a public method that uses internal class as parameter?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am implementing two classes, a parent and a child, in a DDD way. When I want to add a new child, I will do it through the parent.

For that, the method in Parent to add a new child is public, but I wanted the create method in the child to be `internal`, to avoid it is created without doing it through the parent.

These are my classes:

```
public class MyParent
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    string Name { get; private set; }

    // other properties

    public Child AddChild(Child paramChildWithDataToCreateChild)
    {
        Child.Create(paramChildWithDataToCreateChild);
    }
}

internal class Child
{
    internal long Id { get; private set; }
    internal string Name { get; private set; }
    // other properties

    internal Child Create(Child paramChild)
    {
        // Code to create the child
    }
}
```

I can solve the problem if I declare the `AddChild` method as internal in the `Parent` class, but then I will not can create child from another assembly, and if I declare `public` in the `Child` class, then code from other assemblies could create children directly.

Perhaps another option it is to declare the child class as public, but the create method as internal, so it couldn't create children directly, they should go through the parent class.

However, another assembly could has access to the child class directly, and I don't if this is a good idea considering encapsulation.

In summary, I would like to encapsulate much as possible the parent aggregate. How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I see your `Create` method takes in a `Child` as an argument. That's a strange design to begin with. Isn't that just `Clone` and not `Create`?

Comment: Well, it is to ilustrate the case, but perhaps it is not very clear. But the point it is how to implement the encapsulation to avoid direct access from outside to the child class.

Comment: You would usually just expose a public interface, and have your internal classes implement that interface, what am I missing here?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a public method with a parameter of an internal type. The point of a public method is that it can be access from outside the assembly. How could a caller outside the assembly pass an argument of a type that can't be seen outside the assembly?

Comment: It is a compiler error to expose a type name in a public API of a type that is non-public.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thinking about it, yes you are right, it has not sense to have internal paramter if external cosumer can't pass the parameter because it has not access to the type.

Comment: Either pass the parameters one by one and create the child, or pass another object like ChildDto and translate it to a child in the domain method.

Comment: But why do you want to hide the Child class? Isn't it a domain contract (like an entity or a value object)?